# How to pass a variable to reveal modal

Tags: wordpress, reveal.js, zurb-foundation-5

Hello i am developing my own functionality plugin on wordpress and i am stuck on trying to pass a variable from a page to a modal that opens after a link is clicked displaying a delete confirm dialog

The link opening the modal is

```
<a href="<?php echo $passing_var?>" data-reveal-id="deleteModal" class="deleteLink">
    <i class="fi-trash size-24 icolored"></i>
</a>
```

The Modal window code

```
<div id="deleteModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <h2>Are you sure you want to DELETE? <?php echo get_the_title( $passing_var ); ?>  </h2>
    <p class="lead">This cannot be undone</p>
    <a class="deleteButton button" href="#">delete</a>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

How can pass `$passing_var` from the main page to the modal window?

Comment: you can read data attribute of the link..

Comment: You mean using javascript? Can you point me a way to do that or somewhere to read about how to accomplish it ?

Comment: yes we can read attr using js.

Comment: Thanks for the superfast answer and sorry for the edit... Can you point me a way to do that or somewhere to read about how to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 2):

> Set Data Attibute

```
<a data-id="<?php echo $passing_var?>" class="deleteLink">
    <i class="fi-trash size-24 icolored"></i>
</a>
```

> Read data attribute to use in modal

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteLink", function () {
     var dataId = $(this).data('id');
     $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how do i retrieve the passed variable from modal? i tried <?php echo $_GET["id"];?> but it seems it is not the correct way... :(

Comment: Alex that will.be available `var dataId = $(this).data('id');` here in dataId

Comment: What you want to do with that value in php. As per your requirement I will be able to tell you the solution.

Comment: i want to pass the post ID from a wordpress post to the modal and then do some functions with it for example to retrieve post_title,post_meta or even delete the post...is there another way to accomplish that? Thanks for asking and your help...

Comment: should i try a form and some ajax to post on submit? can you help me @Pardeep Dhingra please?

Comment: @Alex If you need few data like title and meta, then you can set as data attr else you have to make an ajax call with the id and can get post data. If you want to delete you can call ajax request with the id.

Comment: can you help me on that with a bunch of sample code or sould i forget the modal thing at all :( . I tried a lot but there are lots of knowledge limitations for me....

Comment: @Alex this link will help you.. http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/287209-i-need-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-and-pass-a-php-var-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: jeremydorn.blogspot.in/2011/02/simple-ajax-with-jqueryui-and-php.html

Comment: Thank you very much @pardeep it seems i can try the method from http://jeremydorn.blogspot.in/2011/02/simple-ajax-with-jqueryui-and-php.html ...If i manage to do it i'll come back for feedback....

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working after a lot of trial and error and google research... nothing unexpected here... :(

So if anybody in the future needs to pass a variable from a page to a modal must follow three steps...

1.Create the modal button

```
<button data-reveal-id="myModal" data-my-number="1">First One</button>
```

2.Add the Modal Dialog

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal"><h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2><p class="lead">The <span class="buttonText"></span>.  It is mine.</p><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>
```

3.Add the Javascript

```
$(document).foundation();$('[data-reveal-id]').on('click', function() {var targetModal = $('#' + $(this).data('revealId'));var newText = $(this).text() +' (' + $(this).data('myNumber') + ')';targetModal.find('.buttonText').text(newText);});
```

Please visit this [link](http://codepen.io/Aleri/pen/urtye) if you want to see a working example... thank you all